# Создать новые строки из строки

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная которая хранит строки текста, текст разделяется пробелами. Как извлечь из переменной слова и расположить с новой строки с последующим выводом на экран?
В моем представлении необходимо найти пробелы через цикл методом indexof, записать их в массив и где-то аккуратно на выводе приписать "\n" Правильно ли моё начинание?

```js
var string = "Регулярные выражения - это шаблоны используемые для сопоставления последовательностей символов в строках.";

var gap = " ";
var pos = 0;
while(pos <= -1) {
  var foundPos = string.indexOf(gap, pos);
  if (foundPos == 1) break;

  alert( foundPos ); 
  pos = foundPos + 1;
  }
```

Comment: Для этого существует метод `split`. А у вас какой-то странный код получается, учитывая что ни одной итерации `while` никогда не выполняется, почему при `foundPos` равном единицы нужно прерывать цикл - тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var string = "Регулярные выражения - это шаблоны используемые для сопоставления последовательностей символов в строках.";

console.log(string.split(' ').join('\n'));

// или раз уж зашла речь о регулярках:

console.log(string.replace(/\s+/g, '\n'));
```

Comment: да, мощная эта штука "регулярка", спасибо за пример, но мне пока рано в этом разбираться. Сейчас мне нужно закреплять знания и разбираться в основах.

Comment: Почему такая строка не срабатывает: alert(string.split(' ').join('\n'));

Comment: @ikar не знаю, у меня срабатывает. Но лучше не пользоваться alert. Используйте console.log либо вывод в DOM